# Function that takes a base class pointer in C++ that is overloaded with a pointer to a subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is the example code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Animal {

};

class Rabbit : public Animal {

};

class Caller {
    public:
    virtual void call(Animal* a) {
        std::cout << "Caller calls animal" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void call(Rabbit* r) {
        std::cout << "Caller calls rabbit" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<Animal*> v;
    Caller c;
    auto a = new Animal();
    auto r = new Rabbit();
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(r);


    for(auto elem : v) {
        c.call(elem);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code can be found here

http://ideone.com/I29g3A

and it outputs:

```
Caller calls animal
Caller calls animal
```

I'm wondering, without casting a specific element to `Rabbit*`, is there a way to get `call(Rabbit *r)` method to get called?

Comment: No. But why do you need to call a different method for the derived type? This defeats the purpose of polymorphism.

Comment: Unrelated, but your program is leaking memory. You don't need `new` for this example, just use do `Animal a;` and `v.push_back(&a)`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm trying to implement the visitor pattern. The visitor has overloaded definition of visit for different class type it needs to visit.

Comment: @KenLi: Then you may want to have a look at Boost.Variant and its `static_visitor<>`. The classic visitor pattern requires `Animal` to have an `accept(Visitor& v)` virtual function and each derived class of `Animal` to override it and do `v.call(this)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, e.g., by jumping through a suitable visitor in your system of polymorphic classes. I think you'll need to use two names instead of `call()`, however. I used `pubCall()` and `call()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Visitor;

class Animal {
public:
    virtual void visit(Visitor&);
};

class Rabbit : public Animal {
    void visit(Visitor&);
};

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void call(Animal* a) = 0;
    virtual void call(Rabbit* r) = 0;
};

void Animal::visit(Visitor& v) {
    v.call(this);
}

void Rabbit::visit(Visitor& v) {
    v.call(this);
}

class Caller
    : Visitor {
public:
    void pubCall(Animal* a) { a->visit(*this); }

private:
    virtual void call(Animal* a) {
        std::cout << "Caller calls animal" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void call(Rabbit* r) {
        std::cout << "Caller calls rabbit" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<Animal*> v;
    Caller c;
    auto a = new Animal();
    auto r = new Rabbit();
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(r);


    for(auto elem : v) {
        c.pubCall(elem);
    }


    return 0;
}
```